# Получить глобально значения переменной JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, laravel

есть задача - передать переменную с массивом данных (таблица ag-grid) из main.js (class) в модальное окно (у нее другой маршрут и описание находится в отдельном blade <sсript>...</sсript>).
Я обычно передавал путем axios через контроллер в модальное окно, но столкнулся с проблемой, что когда количество строк превышает 10 000, начинаются танцы с бубном и потеря производительности, тк большой объем данных уходит в модальное окно и она просто даже не реагирует и падает сервер...
Хочу уйти от передачи через контроллер и забирать переменную  с массивом данных в blade файле из главного JS файла.
Вот как я передавал ранее

```
get_sending(){
    let get_data =[];
    let context=this;
    let api = context.dataSetTable.gridOptions.api;
    api.forEachNodeAfterFilter(function (rowNode) {
        get_data.push(rowNode.data);
    });
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/arm/work_dataset_main/modalAdding',
        data: { header:context.dataSetTable.myHeader, data: get_data}
    }).then(
        function (response) {
            $('#modal_main').html();
            $('#modal_main').html(response.data);
            $('#modalAdding').modal('show');

        }
    ).catch(function (error) {
    });

}
```

Проект на Laravel + ag-grid

Comment: В таком случае - лучше всего: найти кодера, который подпишет nda и будет делать work с тобой А пока, вот немножко рефакторинга, ибо сверху 10 строк текста, снизу какой-то код - тз не понятное (И да, как ты уже сам понял, реализация у тебя заведомо неправильная) ```javascript
function get_sending(){ const get_data = []; const context = this; const api = context.dataSetTable.gridOptions.api; api.forEachNodeAfterFilter((rowNode)=>{ get_data.push(rowNode.data); }); axios({ method: 'post', url: '/arm/work_dataset_main/modalAdding', data: {header: context.dataSetTable.myHeader, data: get_data}, }).t